# Trouble installing 'psycopg2' module in 'PyPy' - windows10

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2, pypy

I am trying to import all modules I need for my code in PyPy and I have installed other modules such as numpy, but I have trouble installing psycopg2.

I'm using pypy3 -
Python 3.6.12 -
[PyPy 7.3.3 with MSC v.1927 32 bit] on win32

1. Firstly, I did   C:\pypy3.6> pypy3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
2. I did: C:\pypy3.6\lib-python>pypy3 -mpip install psycopg2-binary

But I got a lot of errors in terminal such as:

- Creazione della libreria build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\psycopg_psycopg.pypy36-pp73-win32.lib e dell'oggetto build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\psycopg_psycopg.pypy36-pp73-win32.exp
  psycopgmodule.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno _PQfreemem non risolto
- ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2-binary
- psycopgmodule.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno _PQlibVersion non risolto
- psycopgmodule.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno _PQconninfoFree non risolto
- pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno _PQbinaryTuples non risolto
- pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: simbolo esterno _PQsetnonblocking non risolto
- fatal error LNK1120: 83 esterni non risolti
- error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

3. I've also tried: C:\pypy3.6\lib-python>pypy3 -mpip install psycopg2

And got the same errors.

4. Finally, I tried:
   C:\pypy3.6>pypy3 -mpip install C:\pypy3.6\psycopg2_binary-2.8.7.dev0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl

And got:

ERROR: psycopg2_binary-2.8.7.dev0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I would like to know what the problem is?